# What's wrong with my Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to replace sometext by defined text with the help of angular JS.  My html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Directive</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div hello-world>sometext</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and JS is

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: 'true',
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="headline"/><br/>{{headline}}'
  };
});
```

My browser says that,

```
Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'helloWorld' must have exactly one root element....
```

How to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Try to wrap the template inside a div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: 'true',
      template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="headline"/><br/>{{headline}}</div>'
  };
```

should do it. The important part is the `div` tag wrapping the template string.

As Sajeetharan rightly commented, there must be only one wrapper for the template that will replace your directive.

> Otherwise, the replacement operation would result in a single element (the directive) being replaced with multiple elements or nodes, which is unsupported and not commonly needed in practice.

It does not have to be a div, though; so when you have `'replace':true`, your template must be like:

```
<any-tag-you-wish>template content</any-tag-you-wish>
```

---

Please read [doc for template in directive with replace mode on](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt)

Comment: What Changes I have to make if I declare my directive as comment i.e.  <!-- directive:hello-world  -->

Comment: well the change is in the template property of your directive: 'template':'<div><input type="text" ng-model="headline"/><br/>{{headline}}</div>'; will edit the answer...

Comment: Oh sorry, you need this: restrict: 'M'

Comment: Yes. restrict: 'M'. Thanks for helping.